# Проблемы с выводом данных в angular + firebase (firestore)

Tags: firebase, angular5, angular-routing, firestore

Проблема в подгрузке данных с firestore.

При первом появлении данные отображаются, если перейти в другой раздел и вернуться обратно, - нет.

Чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать проблему - рабочий пример пример приложения: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrsruy

Функция получения данных из firestore вынесена в `AppService`, инжектится в `DashboardComponent` и оттуда уже вызывается, сохраняя данные в локальную переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/empty';

import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
    private userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User> | Observable<never> = EMPTY;

    public users$: Observable<User[]> = EMPTY;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
        this.userCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users');
        this.users$ = this.userCollection.valueChanges().pipe(
            take(1) // <======= добавили эту строчку
        );
    }

    public getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.users$.toPromise();
    }
}
```

Конвертируем стрим в промис, чтобы не делать подписку и она не висела в памяти, так как вы все равно не отписываетесь:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class DashboardComponent {
    public users: User[] = [];

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {
        this.appService.getUsers().then((users) => {
            this.users = users;
        });
    }
}
```